# iPhone 6/7/8 Plus causing bootstrap navbar issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So i'm trying to iron out bugs on a website that recently went live, On the device mentioned when the bootstrap "hamburger" is pressed the nav menu will appear and disappear straight afterwords. The issue doesn't occur when the screen size is changed to an iphones dimensions, it only happens on the device.

```
<div id="page" class="site">
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'bootstrap2wordpress' ); ?></a>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="main-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>"><img alt="Agnes Burke" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.svg" width="120px"></a>
            </div>

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu ( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'container' => 'nav',
                    'container_id' => 'navbar',
                    'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                    'menu' => 'Main Menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'
                    )
                );
            ?>
            <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I know there is an issue with the jumbotron image too but the navbar is priority.

If any of you could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

LIVE SITE:

https://agnesburkehairdressing.ie/

Comment: Get rid of multiple `bootstrap.js` included in your page. and always declare your `bootstrap.js` after `jquery.js`

Comment: Your Meta Viewports also don't line up with what Bootstrap suggests, and when I try to load your Bootstrap CSS it turns up a 404 error.